# Passing arguments to xelatex using latexmk

Tags: xetex, latexmk

I have a single XeLaTeX source file which can generate two versions of the document depending on whether a certain command sequence `testcs` exists.  I typically have a shell script which generates both versions, which looks like this:

```csh
set file = "Document"
xelatex -jobname="${file}-v1" "\def\testcs{1} \input{${file}.tex}"
xelatex ${file}.tex
```

I have now included an index in my document and typesetting it now requires several passes through `xelatex`.  I would typically use `latexmk`, such as

```
latexmk -pdfxe Document
```

but I now would like to generate the two versions of the document using my script.

In other words, I would like to modify my shell script to use `latexmk`, but I seem unable to pass the arguments to `xelatex`.  I can pass the `-jobname` but I've had no such luck passing the `\def\textcs{1}` via any of the options: `-xelatex`, `-pdfxelatex`, `-pretex`,...

**Question**  Is there a simple way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58259870/403757) is due to user @samcarter in [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com):

```csh
set file = "Document"
latexmk -pdfxe -jobname=${file}"-v1" -pretex="\def\testcs{1}" -usepretex ${file}
```